# How to get current context in Microsoft Bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I am building a form using `FormDialog` to which I am passing a `BuildFormDelegate` parameter (a static method). In this method, I need the context to acquire user data.

The user data is stored as part of context written using an extension:

```
public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(this IBotContext context, string resourceId)
```

I call the form context as follows:

```
var calendarform = new FormDialog<CalendarInput>(new CalendarInput(), MakeCalendarForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, result);
context.Call<CalendarInput>(calendarform, CalendarFormComplete);
```

I need to call the `GetAccessToken` method in the `MakeCalendarForm` (which does not take any argument). How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is `MakeCalendarForm`? What's stopping you from calling `GetAccessToken` inside it?

Comment: MakeCalendarForm is a static method. It is similar to BuildForm method in  [link](http://mayoster.blogspot.in/2016/05/bot-builder-formflow.html). The context is not available in this method to call GetAccessToken method.

Comment: Also GetAccessToken is async method. It cannot be called from the MakeCalendarForm which returns IForm<CalendarInput>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the GetAccessToken before calling the form and pass the resulting token as parameter to the CalendarInput state your passing to the FormDialog you are creating. Something like

```
var token = await context.GetAccessToken();
var calendarform = new FormDialog<CalendarInput>(new CalendarInput(token), MakeCalendarForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, result);
```

However, it sounds strange that you need the token in context of the Form. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I needed the token because the options for the fields of the form have to be fetched from a web service.

Comment: Great! If possible, I would retrieve the options before calling the form and pass them to the form state (as you are doing now with the access token)